# Why is "if" used in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Someone said

> "Losing a child is a horrific thing if you are a parent."

Does that mean that he isn't a parent?  Is "if" always used in a questioning context? Should he have used "when" instead if he was talking as a man who was a parent?

Comment: In this sentence, `if` is used to introduce a qualifier. Perhaps the example doesn't need a qualifier, since losing a child should be horrific for everybody, not just parents.

Comment: Sometimes you will hear `if` used as to denote a qualifier in giving instructions: _You are to call the 911 **if and only if** there is an emergency_.

Comment: @CharlesAddis: A pediatric surgeon can also lose a child, but is likely less horrified than the child's parents. It depends on how you define "losing a child" (i.e. does it inherently mean "losing **your own** child"?)

Answer (score 1):

There are various similar ways of phrasing (just as there are in other languages).

For example:

- Losing a child is a horrific thing *if* you are a parent.
- Losing a child is a horrific thing *when* you are a parent.
- Losing a child is a horrific thing *for* a parent.
- Losing a child is a horrific thing *to* a parent.

The same concept exists in all these variations - the loss of a child and that this has a strong emotional impact on the parent of that child.

The *if* / *when* interchangeability here is like that of *wenn* in German which can also be used for both *if* and *when*.

Update: Robert's point on the use of *you* reminded me that in English there is not the distinction between impersonal, personal, direct and indirect. That is, *you* is written the same whether directly addressing someone, referring to someone indirectly, addressing someone in the singular or addressing in the plural.

As such, this can also be phrased (using a more formal form of speech):

- Losing a child is a horrific thing *if* one is a parent.
- Losing a child is a horrific thing *when* one is a parent.

where the use of *one* indicates a non-specific person.

Answer (score 1):

The sub context of this sentence I believe is the word "especially"

> "Losing a child is a horrific thing [especially] if you are a parent."

The sentence is very general, it doesn't necessarily mean that the speaker is/isn't a parent but rather that losing a child is horrific for parents in general.

The reason I say this is because we don't know which "you" is being used in this sentence. The speaker could mean "one" (i.e. everyone, the general "you") or "you" meaning everyone excluding themselves.

Generally, it considered pretty formal to use the word "one" and so "you" has commonly been accepted to be generic.

Answer (score 0):

I think Vjm is confused because The speaker said "you" when not referring to a specific person. In this context, you means anybody, not just the person who he is talking to directly. Out of that anybody, only the people who are parents consider it horrific.